# Cross browser compatibility A href and Button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<input type="button" onclick="staff.updateDetail({$T.list.id},'staffno');" title="Change Details" value="{$T.list.staff_no}">

<a href="#" title="Change Details" style="color: #000" onclick="staff.updateDetail({$T.list.id},'staffno');">{$T.list.staff_no}</a>
```

it has jquery, php running on it.

that code works well in google chrome and smoothly run the function, but when i run my program in mozilla firefox, it doesnt work anything when I click it.

how can I solve this, I think it is about cross browser compatibility.

Thanks in advance...

TypeError: staff.updateDetail is not a function

firebug says this in error:

```
TypeError: staff.updateDetail is not a function
staff.updateDetail(1001,'staffno');
```

and in script :

```
function onclick(event) {
staff.updateDetail(1001,'staffno');
}
```

why? why but why is it running in google chrome?

I have a js.file named staff.js and it has staff class and updateDetail function on it...

Comment: You can start by opening the console in FF and read possible error messages...

Comment: can you share the page url, may be we can investigate better

Comment: http://localhost/att/index3.html# :D

Comment: Put `console.log(staff.updateDetail)` into `onclick` before calling the function. This way you'll find out, which `staff.updateDetail` actually is.

Comment: thanks for the help guys, now they are both working in many browsers I realized that I just need to flush cache and redownload page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I checked dummy html page with your two lines in validator http://validator.w3.org. It reported:

```
 Bad value staff.updateDetail({$T.list.id},'staffno'); for attribute onclick on element input: missing : after property id

 Bad value staff.updateDetail({$T.list.id},'staffno'); for attribute onclick on element a: missing : after property id
```

Firefox reports in console:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
    staff.updateDetail({$T.list.id},'staffno');
```

What is `{$T.list.id}`? It looks like object but there is no property.

Comment: Looks like `{$T.list.id}` === `1001` ; ).

Comment: What do you expect in method staff.updateDetail()? Which kind of parameters?